# error : unrecognized arguments (python)

Tags: python, arguments, argparse, object-detection

Here is the source of this code: [github - datitran/Object-Detector-App]

The code below is part of the complete code. 
I have made that code into an .exe file.

When I run the .exe file, I get an error saying 'unrecognized arguments'. 
Please let me know how to fix this error.

Thanks

[enter link description here](https://github.com/datitran/Object-Detector-App/blob/master/object_detection_app.py) <- code here.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-src', '--source', dest='video_source', type=int,
                    default=0, help='Device index of the camera.', )
parser.add_argument('-wd', '--width', dest='width', type=int,
                    default=960, help='Width of the frames in the video stream.')
parser.add_argument('-ht', '--height', dest='height', type=int,
                    default=720, help='Height of the frames in the video stream.')
parser.add_argument('-num-w', '--num-workers', dest='num_workers', type=int,
                    default=2, help='Number of workers.')
parser.add_argument('-q-size', '--queue-size', dest='queue_size', type=int,
                    default=5, help='Size of the queue.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

error :

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[DEBUG/MainProcess] Queue._start_thread()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] doing self._thread.start()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] starting thread to feed data to pipe
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ... done self._thread.start()
usage: object_detection_app.exe [-h] [-src VIDEO_SOURCE] [-wd WIDTH]
                            [-ht HEIGHT] [-num-w NUM_WORKERS]
                            [-q-size QUEUE_SIZE]
object_detection_app.exe: error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-    fork pipe_handle=1656 parent_pid=14676
usage: object_detection_app.exe [-h] [-src VIDEO_SOURCE] [-wd WIDTH]
                            [-ht HEIGHT] [-num-w NUM_WORKERS]
                            [-q-size QUEUE_SIZE]
object_detection_app.exe: error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork pipe_handle=1672 parent_pid=14676
```

Comment: You haven't posted relevant part of the code. The problem is that `object_detection_app.exe` is getting called with a parameter it doesn't support (`--multiprocessing-fork`), but this is happening not in the posted code but elsewhere.

Comment: Does `Object-Detector-App/object_detection_app.py` run for you when not converted to `exe`?  As a standalone script? The error indicates that it's being called with some sort of multiprocessing argument list, with strings that have nothing to do with the `parser` defined in this file.

Comment: @hpaulj 
It will run well before converting to exe. The 'object_detection_app.py' code uses the webcam. I was converting because the webcam's response was slow. However, it does not run...!

Comment: In any case you'll have to either change how the wrapper calls this script (with correct arguments), or change the parser so it can handle the one's it's given.  `parse_known_args` might do the trick.